# Variance of a complete group of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

Let's say I have a dataframe with 10+1 columns and 10 rows, and every value has the same units except for one column (the "grouping" column A).
I'm trying to accomplish the following: given a grouping of the data frames based on the last column, how do I compute the standard deviation of the whole block as a single, monolithic variable.

Let's say I do the grouping (in reality it's a `cut` in intervals):

```
df %>% group_by(A)
```

From what I have gathered trhoughout this site, you can use aggregate or other dplyr methods to calculate variance **per column**, i.e.:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiTM3.png) (SO won't let me embed if I have <10 rep).
In that picture we can see the grouping as colors, but by using aggregate I would get 1 standard deviation per specified column (I know you can use `cbind` to get more than 1 variable, for example `aggregate(cbind(V1,V2)~A, df, sd)`) and per group (and similar methods using `dplyr` and `%>%`, with `summarise(..., FUN=sd)` appended at the end).

However what I want is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43XaG.png): just like in Matlab when you do

```
group1 = df(row_group,:) % row_group would be df(:,end)==1 in this case
stdev(group1(:)) % operator (:) is key here
% iterate for every group
```

I have my reasons for wanting it that specific way, and of course the real dataframe is bigger than this mock example.

Minimum working example:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10),c(1,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1)))
colnames(df) <- c(paste0("V",seq(1,10)),"A")

df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_at(vars(V1), funs(sd(.))) # no good
aggregate(V1~A, data=df, sd) # no good
aggregate(cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10)~A, data=df, sd) # nope
df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_at(vars(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10), funs(sd(.))) # same as above...
```

Result should be 3 doubles, each with the sd of the group (which should be close to 1 if enough columns are added).

Comment: Added the example. Can't see how it will help you though. I can only put what I have tried and do not want, which I thought was much better explained by the pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a base R solution, try the following.

```
sp <- split(df[-1], cut(df$A, breaks=c(2.1)))
lapply(sp, function(x) var(unlist(x)))
#$`(0.998,2]`
#[1] 0.848707
#
#$`(2,3]`
#[1] 1.80633
```

I have coded it in two lines to make it clearer but you can avoid the creation of `sp` and write the one-liner

```
lapply(split(df[-1], cut(df$A, breaks=c(2.1))), function(x) var(unlist(x)))
```

Or, for a result in another form,

```
sapply(sp, function(x) var(unlist(x)))
#(0.998,2]     (2,3] 
# 0.848707  1.806330
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(6322)    # make the results reproducible
df <- data.frame(cbind(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10),c(1,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1)))
colnames(df) <- c(paste0("V",seq(1,10)),"A")
```

Comment: Ok, I can admit it because it works with `cut` which was critical to me!
For completion, I will put the cut-based approach here:

    sp <- split(df[-1], cut(df$A,breaks=c(2.1)))
    lapply(sp, function(x) var(unlist(x)))

Giving:

$`(0.998,2]`
[1] 1.066936

$`(2,3]`
[1] 1.040392

(I changed the distribution to a normal with sd = 1 to better check if it was really working)

Comment: @adrianB I have changed the code to use your data and `cut`. I have also set the RNG seed to make the results reproducible.